# Не запускаются perl cкрипты в apache

Tags: apache, macos, perl, apache-modules

Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.06. Выполнил эту инструкцию https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-12034, также раскомментировал загрузку модуля mod_cgi, но perl скрипты все равно не выполняются, браузер предлагает их скачать.

```
sudo apachectl -M
```

показывает, что модули perl_module и cgi_module загружены

вот error_log после перезагрузки

```
[Tue Dec 10 11:02:01.586530 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 77] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using MacBook-Air-Nikita.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Dec 10 11:02:01.912225 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 504] AH00163: Apache/2.4.33 (Unix) PHP/7.1.16 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.18.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 10 11:02:01.912331 2019] [core:notice] [pid 504] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

скрипты на php работают

Что делать?

Answer (score -1):

> Что делать?

Посмотреть в сторону Mojolicious или Dancer + NGINX. CGI мертв, используйте PSGI.
Apache не нужен.